# Join 2 data frames by columns when the nr of observations are different

Tags: r, dataframe

How to merge 2 data frames if the number of columns are different:

```
df1 structure: 

  t1 t2 t3
  0  0  0
  1  1  1
  1  1  1
  1  1  1



df2 structure (has ZERO observations ): 

  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
```

Output:

```
 t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
  0  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0
```

Sample data:

```
df1<-structure(list( t1=c(0,1,1,1), t2=c(0,1,1,1),t3 = c(0,1,1,1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

df2<-structure(list( t1=c(), t2=c(),t3 = c(),t4 = c(),t5 = c()), row.names = c(NA, 0L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to find the column names that are present in 'df2' and not in 'df1' and assign those columns to 0 in 'df1'

```
df1[setdiff(names(df2), names(df1))] <- 0
```

-output

```
df1
#  t1 t2 t3 t4 t5
#1  0  0  0  0  0
#2  1  1  1  0  0
#3  1  1  1  0  0
#4  1  1  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option might be using `merge`, e.g.,

```
replace(out <- merge(df1,df2,all = TRUE),is.na(out),0)
```